# JSLint: Read Only error when setting console even though it's set as writable global

Tags: javascript, debugging, jslint

Consider the following code:

```
/*global console:true */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    //set console for browsers without debugger
    if (!console) {
        console = {
            log: function() {}
        };
    }
});
```

This will throw an error:

```
Error:
Problem at line 7 character 9: Read only.

console = {

Problem at line 7 character 9: Stopping. (3% scanned).
```

Yet, console has been set as a writeable global, thus it should not be read only.

Any suggestions on how to circumvent or solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to repro this on the jslint.com website but had no luck, except by replacing `true` with `false`.  Are you using the command line tool, or the website?

Comment: @bbg, I'm trying it on the website, http://jslint.com/. Quite weird that you cannot reproduce it. I tried it again, with no luck.

Comment: Aha, do you have the `Assume console, alert...` box checked?  If so, try unchecking it.

Comment: @bbg, that did the trick. I should have thought about that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: excellent.  I added the same comment as an answer, but now it's just redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and tried it into www.jslint.com, had to change two small things but it gives me no errors  now (added one space after "function" and added the self invokation) :

```
/*global console:true */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    //set console for browsers without debugger
    if (!console) {
        console = {
            log: function () {}
        };
    }
}());
```

Where did you try it?

Comment: Fixed, with help of bbg, quote: "Aha, do you have the Assume console, alert... box checked? If so, try unchecking it.".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the jslint.com website, and you have the `Assume console, alert, ...` box checked, try unchecking it.